# Is it possible to test mobile device through usb to usb port from hub

Tags: android, external-accessory, usb-otg

I tried to build App to debug with an external device I want to debug while connecting external device. How can I achieve that
I am using type C USB hub and trying to test with USB - USB cable but failed.

Answer (score 2):

You can test with USB - USB (USB hub). But may be here is a problem with your USB cable. Some USB cables are only for charging. In that case you should change your USB cable.